# How can I disable NHibernate lazy loading for a total application?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

In a special case we do not want to change mapping files and adding lazy="false" to each of them because of upgrading NHibernate. Is it possible to disable lazy loading in a total application by just adding something to app.config or web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell you will have to change the mapping files. I might be wrong but I couldn't find any global setting.

If you didn't want to change the class definition you could define it in the root element of each mapping file you have:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.0" default-lazy="false">
```